# Count the number of a which $\gcd($sum-of-digits$(a),$ sum-of-square-of-digits$(a)) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Called a is **good** if $\gcd($*sum-of-digits*$(a),$ *sum-of-square-of-digits*$(a)) = 1$
I find that if *sum-of-digits*$(a)$ is odd and $\gcd($*all digits of* $a) = 1$ then $a$ is **good**. But I can't prove that.

I have used modulo 2, 3, 5, 7 to prove that.
Is that right???

And the most important question is how to count the number of $a$ not exceeding $10^{18}$

Comment: $111,117,124,139$ are counterexamples.   I made a spreadsheet to check the numbers $100-999$.  Using modulos cannot solve this as it only involves the digits of the number.

Comment: Note that whether a number is good does not depend on the order of the digits, just on the multiset of them.  You only need to consider the multisets of up to $18$ digits, then for each that is good count the number of numbers it represents.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a = \overline{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}$ is good so that $\gcd(a_1+\dots+a_n, a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2) = 1.$ Since $a_i^2 \equiv a_i \mod 2,$ the sum and sum of squares have the same parity, proving that the sum must be odd. If $d|\gcd(a_1, \dots, a_n),$ then $d$ divides the sum and sum of squares, proving the 2nd condition is also necessary.

However, these conditions are not sufficient: $111$ is not good despite the fact $1+1+1 = 3$ is odd and $\gcd(1, 1, 1) = 1.$ To count the number not exceeding $10^{18}$ is a programming problem, I suggest you ask on another SE.